# Hardy-Weinberg applied to three alleles and stimation of allele frequencies

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, population-biology, molecular-evolution

I have this equation:
Corresponds to HW in equilibria with three alleles:

$(p+q+r)^2=1$

Expanding the square results:

$p^2+2pq+r^2+2pr+q^2+2qr = 1$

I need to separate homozygous and heterozygous, that means:
$2pq+2pr+2qr=1-p^2-q^2-r^2$

How I can use a equivalence similar to $(p=1-q) or (q=1-p)$ in two alleles to resolve the last equation?

Comment: in this case it will be `r=1-p-q` and similarly for others

Comment: Why do you need to separate homozygotes from heterozygotes?

Comment: I'm with jkadlubowska - what's the purpose of separating hetero and homozygotes?

Comment: To calculate the proportion of the alleles (p, q and r), if the homozygotes are three times than heterozygotes.

Comment: So you omitted some data of this question? The thing is, you can substitute whatever you want, e.g. 1-p=q+r or p=1-q-r, but that leads you nowhere if you don't have any more data. Something like p^2+q^2+r^2=3pq+3pr+3rq is crucial to solving this problem. Anyway - these are two equasions, you still need a third to ba able to assign specific numbers to p, q and r.

Comment: i think WYSIWYG has answered this question.  can't do much more unless you have a further answer you are looking for

Comment: I agree with jkadlubowska that some information is missing.  If you want numerical values, the number of equations must be equal to the number of variables.  Otherwise, the best you can do is solve for two variables in terms of the other. Did you want to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everybody said it already, but there is none.  The original HWE equation ($(p+q)^2=1$) works because you've got two variables and two equations ($p+q=1$) to work with (in reality, these are just one equation and one variable, since $q=1-p$ so $p+(1-p))^2=1$).  Now you have three variables and still only the one equation ($p+q+r=1$) which is, mathematically, impossible.

You need go out and measure some frequencies.  In particular, you need to measure two of them - I'd choose two of the homozygous types for convenience's sake.

This basically summarizes everything nicely for ya: http://www.bio.miami.edu/dana/dox/trinomial.html

Comment: mathematically impossible -> mathematically insolvable.  Its quite possible.